# Best way to navigate a main menu on android

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

So right now I have my main activity with several buttons (one being "About"). The way I handled changing the screen to display about info, is by adding this an onClickListener:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), About.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

About.java then sets the content view to a different layout that includes a back button. The back button is handled in the same way as described about and leads back to the main activity.

The thing I noticed though is that when I run the app and click "about", then "back", It will be running 2 main activities and 1 about activity. So is there a better method to handle menus like this, or can I just add something to Intent code to make it close the current activity before proceeding to the next?

Edit:
Oh wow, thanks guy, I didn't even think about that. I'm a little sleep deprived right now.

Comment: note related to your question but, I guess there is no need for you to call startActivityForResult() since your About activity won't generate any results. so you can use startActivity() insted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't launch a new activity to return to your previous one.
You simply call `finish();` on your about activity when you click the back button to return to the previous activity on the backstack..

Or, you could do it the "Android way" and not put a back button in, not worry about calling `finish()`, and just allow the user to press the back button on their phone (all Android phones have them) to return to the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `finish()` on the `MainActivity` and then create a new `MainActivity` from an `Intent` inside the `About` class. But a better way might just be to not `finish()` your `MainActivity` and just `finish()` your about class. This will take you to your previous `MainActivity` that you already have running. Also, this will allow you to call `About` from other activities if you wish and return to wherever you called it from